# Updating an arugement of a ModSecurity Core Rule

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-security

I have a big form that probably needs to send 1000 `POST DATA` arguments at most. Sometimes it would triggers a false alarm from rule `960335` of the OWASP Core rulset. I looked into that rule in `modsecurity_crs_23_request_limits.conf` but I can't figure out how to set the max_num_args higher on that specific form.

In `modsecurity_crs_60_customrules.conf`, I have tried:

```
<LocationMatch "/form.php"> 

  SecRuleUpdateTargetById 960335 ARGS:"@gt %1000"

</LocationMatch>
```

But the syntax check gave me this error

```
`Updating target by ID with no ruleset in this context`
```

Can anyone tell me how to set the max_num_args higher?

Here's rule `960335`:

```
SecRule &TX:MAX_NUM_ARGS "@eq 1" "chain,phase:2,t:none,block,
msg:'Too many arguments in request',id:'960335',
severity:'4',rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'9',
accuracy:'9',tag:'OWASP_CRS/POLICY/SIZE_LIMIT'"

SecRule &ARGS "@gt %{tx.max_num_args}" "t:none,setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',
setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.notice_anomaly_score},
setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/POLICY/SIZE_LIMIT-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is set in the modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf file:

```
# -- Maximum number of arguments in request limited
SecAction \
  "id:'900006', \
  phase:1, \
  t:none, \
  setvar:tx.max_num_args=255, \
  nolog, \
  pass"
```